# Code screws up when viewport changes

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following function which makes the 'up-btn' appear at the bottom of my page when the user scrolls 250px from the bottom ( and not on mobile)

**html ( in head tags )**

```
<script>
 if ($(window).width() > 768) {
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > ($(document).height() - 250)) {
        $("#up-btn").fadeIn(500);
    } else {
        $("#up-btn").fadeOut(500);
    }
   });
 };
</script>
```

**html (body)**

```
<a id="up-btn" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="scrolltop();"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up fa-lg"></i></a>
```

It works properly. However, when i scale the window to mobile then to ceen size. Or if the window opens at mobile size, etc. the code doesn't work and the button remains invisible.

Wondering if there's changes to my code that would make it more foolproof?

Comment: I have another function that controls the scrolling which is why its there. There is no issues with that code.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `if`-statement:

```
<script>
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > ($(document).height() - 250)) {
      $("#up-btn").fadeIn(500);
    }
    else {
        $("#up-btn").fadeOut(500);
    }
  });
</script>
```

When that is said, you might consider debouncing the function, to avoid having the recalculate all the time, eg. recalculate when the scrolling stops.

Comment: don't i need the if statement to calculate if the user is at the bottom of the page or not?

Comment: @user3550879 The if statement that only runs your code if `$(window).width() > 768`. (Hint I removed it in the posted code)

Comment: @user3550879 You want the code that sets up the "scroll" listener to run no matter what. What you do *inside* of that listener is up to you.

Comment: oh ok, I do want it not to work on mobile (remain hidden) and only work on screens. I figured I needed to add that, but it seemed to screw up when returned back to screen size